# Get results of Scrapy Request

Tags: python, request, scrapy

How to get results of scrapy request in a usable variable.

```
 def parse_node(self,response,node):
    yield Request('LINK',callback=self.parse_listing)
 def parse_listing(self,response):
    for agent in string.split(response.xpath('//node[@id="Agent"]/text()').extract_first() or "",'^'):
       HERE=Request('LINK',callback=self.parse_agent)
       print HERE
 def parse_agent(self,response):
    yield response.xpath('//node[@id="Email"]/text()').extract_first()
```

I am trying to get results from my  `HERE=Request('LINK',callback=self.parse_agent)` and print them. The parse_agent should pick up an email but I would like to get it and use it inside parse_listing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments under the first answer, I think what you really need is using [`scrapy-inline-requests`](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests) for the purpose (see the example there). Your code would look something like this:

```
def parse_node(self, response, node):
    yield Request('LINK', callback=self.parse_listing)

@inline_requests
def parse_listing(self, response):
    for agent in string.split(response.xpath('//node[@id="Agent"]/text()').extract_first() or "",'^'):
        agent_response = yield Request('LINK')
        email = agent_response.xpath('//node[@id="Email"]/text()').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse_listing(self, response):
    for agent in string.split(response.xpath('//node[@id="Agent"]/text()').extract_first() or "", '^'):
        HERE = scrapy.Request('LINK', callback=self.parse_agent)
        # call this req or something calls parse_agent(link)
        yield HERE # this will yield to callback which will print or log


def parse_agent(self, response):
     print response #response is the parsed page from HERE)
     email = response.xpath('//node[@id="Email"]/text()').extract_first() #something 

     print email # logging is better 
     #import logging
     #logging.log(logging.INFO, "info from page")
     yield email #yield to whatever function
```

Comment: How do I get "email" from parse_agent into parse_listing?

Comment: parse agent can only pass info to parse listing if it yields a callback. callback=self.parse_agent this is how scrapy flow works. method1 parses start link, method2 yields to method3 and so on     scrapy.Request(link, callback={methodname}

Comment: let me know if you need more clarification - thx. I realize this and your other  question are related. My other answer should help.